# I am currently trying to execute an App script in Google Ads that is triggered when there is a specific value set in a cell A1 of a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently have a script that will remove a negative keywords from a shared negative keyword list when run.

I would like to have this script run when a specific value for example "run" is put in a cell A1 of a an external google sheet.

Below is the current code I have with out the trigger.

```js
function main() {
  removeAllNegativeKeywordsFromList();
}


function removeAllNegativeKeywordsFromList() {
  var NEGATIVE_KEYWORD_LIST_NAME = 'test';

  var negativeKeywordListIterator =
      AdsApp.negativeKeywordLists()
          .withCondition('Name = "' + NEGATIVE_KEYWORD_LIST_NAME + '"')
          .get();

  if (negativeKeywordListIterator.totalNumEntities() == 1) {
    var negativeKeywordList = negativeKeywordListIterator.next();
    var sharedNegativeKeywordIterator =
        negativeKeywordList.negativeKeywords().get();

    var sharedNegativeKeywords = [];

    while (sharedNegativeKeywordIterator.hasNext()) {
      sharedNegativeKeywords.push(sharedNegativeKeywordIterator.next());
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < sharedNegativeKeywords.length; i++) {
      sharedNegativeKeywords[i].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried connecting the script to a google sheet and having it run when i put the trigger word in, however it does not seem to work

I did not enter the trigger i used as it think it is completely wrong. the code is without the trigger

Run above script when the word "run" is put in cell A1 of an external google sheet.`enter code here`

Comment: Share your [Stackdriver logs / errors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) and how you attempted to trigger this function. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood right you are only looking for the trigger for this code. To trigger your code when 'run' is inserted into A1 you would use onEdit(e)

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  // Your testword
  var theword = 'run';

  // Get the value in cell
  var value = e.value;

  // Check the range. You could use the spreadsheet->cell->getvalue() but
  // this should perform better as calling the SheetApp - API is costly
  var isA1 = (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1);

  // if the word and the range both match
  if( isA1 && (value == theword)) 
  {
    // Run your code
    removeAllNegativeKeywordsFromList();
  }
}
```

The trigger itself is tested and working, but as for your code I could not confirm that as I do not know if your 'removeAllNegativeKeywordsFromList' works in the first place. In case you need any help with that please advise some more with this AdsApp, please.

Also please note that any user calling this function via onEdit has to authorise it first. This can be done by running it from script editor or creating a specific authorise-function.

Hope this helps at all.

Comment: An edit of range A1:E500 would meet your condition of `isA1` (although `e.value` will then be `undefined` since it is a multi-cell edit). Also note that a simple trigger (using the reserved name `onEdit` is one such trigger) cannot ever call services requiring authorization. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions

Comment: @tehhowch did you try it with the A1:E500 range? I tested it out and it worked, e.value  was not null. I thought about adding the range.columnEnd and range.rowEnd to the test, but since the point was the value in the specific cell, not the selected range I chose this way.  Also onEdit can be called after it has been authorized, so I used this reserved trigger on purpose. I have tested it and actually used it a lot, but please correct me if my information is outdated.

Comment: My comment was based on the specified behavior for a multi-cell edit in the official documentation. consider changing to `e.range.getA1Notation() === "A1". As far as using a name that binds a simple trigger as the name of a function receiving an installed trigger, do not do that. The simple trigger still fires, and it fires for all edits by any editor, generating spurious error logs and possibly consuming quotas. It's a terrible idea.

Comment: Of course I/we can edit that, in case the answer itself is good enough. To clarify, I used the installed onEdit trigger on a purpose. The question was to *when a specific value for example "run" is put in a cell A1*. In the first place I am trying to answer the question asked, although I also supposed this sheet would not be used for other activity than adding words. Of course the user could manually trigger the code, which is worth pointing of course, but would not answer the question, I think. I appreciate your feedback here, My only intention was to provide a good answer and some help.

Comment: Again, any function receiving an installed trigger should never be named such that it also binds any simple trigger. To do so, even in example code, perpetuates bad practice that can lead to unexpected and difficult to debug behavior, especially for new developers that are more likely to use code without understanding the intricacies involved.

Comment: This makes sense. However it does not actually have any call or reference to a google sheet. The script will be housed in google adwords and will need to get the information from the external google sheet. Forgive me if my explanation was a bit misleading. SO technically, I would have to get the sheet and then get the range and check the range? this is where i get lost.